# "Microsoft My Phone" alternative for ubuntu

Tags: sound, bluetooth, android

I'm looking for a good alternative for Microsoft My Phone for Ubuntu.
Something that lets me connect my phone either via USB or BT to my computer and place/receive calls. It shall preferably also funnel the sound from my phone to the computer. All in all it shall make my computer behave as a BT handsfree.

Best Regards

EDIT: As I stated earlier, it connects your phone via BT to the computer and acts a bit like a BT handsfree. It lets you make calls on the phone via the computer, write text-messages and  so on. Also, when you make calls, it lets you use the microphone and speakers on your computer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Have a look at KDEConnect/GSConnect. It can ring the phone wirelessly, when they are on the same network. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/11/connect-android-ubuntu-gsconnect https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/09/gsconnect-android-media-controls-update

Comment: What does Microsoft My Phone do? Many of us have not used Windows 10, and are not familiar with the recent features of Windows.
Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1322477/edit) your question and describe what Microsoft My Phone does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Archisman, but KDEConnect/GSConnect is missing one very important feature. The ability to make phonecalls via your computer.

Comment: I know a partial solution. Would it work for you if you can completely control the touch screen of your phone from your computer, but attend the phone call with the phone's speaker/microphone (using either loudspeaker or earphones connected to your phone)? If it works for you, I would write an answer.